# ViewPager view doesn't update page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I currently have a `ViewPager` with a lot of pages. Now I also have an array full of strings to fill a `TextView` on each page. But when I load the strings in the `TextView` it doesn't show the string. But when I swipe to the next page and back it will be there. But the next page doesn't have the string either until I swipe to the next page and back.

This is the code in my `onPageSelected` method. But this code was also in my `onCreateView` method.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    position02 = position;
    date = dates[position];
    Log.d("POSITION", String.valueOf(position));
    Log.d("POSITION02", String.valueOf(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()));


    TextView actionBarDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionBarDay);
    TextView actionBarMonth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionBarMonth);
    TextView actionBarYear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionBarYear);


    String date = dates[mViewPager.getCurrentItem()];

    actionBarDay.setText(date.substring(0,2));
    actionBarMonth.setText(date.replaceAll ("[0-9]", ""));
    actionBarYear.setText(date.substring(Math.max(0, date.length() - 4)));

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    try {
        //date = date.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        //Log.d("TEST1", "d" + date);
        //int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("d" + date, "string", packageName);
        //String text = getResources().getString(resId);
        String text = texts[position];
        textView.setText(text);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My `PagerAdapter` class:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        position01 = position;
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 366;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same result when the code was in your `onCreateView` method?

Comment: Can you Paste your PagerAdapter class?

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh yes.